# What does this error TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable mean?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first time coding in tkinter. When I try to create a new button in the function 'Registering' i keep getting the same error  'Button' object is not callable. I don't understand what this error is suggesting about the simple code I have written. Can anyone clarify this for me in the context of the code below?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def Registering():
    window = Toplevel(root)
    login_button = Button(window, width = 120, height = 42)



Button = Button(root,text= "Enter",command=Registering)
Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have named your variable `Button`, hence shadowing the `Button` class from `tkinter`

Answer (score 12):

```
Button = Button(root,text= "Enter",command=Registering)
Button.pack()
```

By doing `Button = Button (...` you override tkinter's definition of `Button`.

Use a different (hopefully more meaningful) name:

```
register_button = Button(root,text= "Enter",command=Registering)
register_button.pack()
```

Comment: Might be good to also add the recommendation to not do `from tkinter import *`

Answer (score 0):

the reason its showing the error is cause ur using  Button as ur variable name

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def Registering():
    window = Toplevel(root)
    login_button = Button(window, width = 120, height = 42)



btn= Button(root,text= "Enter",command=Registering)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```